# How to integrate a file picker with WASM?

Tags: uno-platform

I want to upload an image from my PC and show it in a grid view.

How can I choose images from my PC and list them out in WASM?

Comment: You mean how to integrate a [file picker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) in your app?

You may be able to access the directory directly in most browsers.  Maybe the usage of the [`FileSystem` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) will help here... it depends if you can use it.

You must take into consideration you're running in a browser, so you have the same restrictions of any javascript running in a webpage.

Comment: Yes I am trying to integrate a file picker. I will see if I can use  FileSystem API in this case.

Comment: I'm currently drafting a blog post to explain how to integrate HTML stuff into Uno-Warm. I'll check if I can fit your need in it... since I'm pretty sure it will be a recurring request for Uno-Wasm.

Comment: That would be much appreciated, thank you, good sir.

Comment: Check https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/508

Answer (score 2):

Official support for this was added in [Uno 3.6](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/releases/tag/3.6.6). You can use the [FilePicker APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) to pick files and folders on any platform.

```cs
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
    this.textBlock.Text = "Picked photo: " + file.Name;
}
else
{
    this.textBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. See https://platform.uno/docs/articles/features/windows-storage-pickers.html - "While the SuggestedStartLocation has currently no effect in Uno Platform targets, it must be set, otherwise the dialog crashes on UWP. FileTypes must include at least one item."

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer with the file type filter. Should work.